# giving turns for attacks in mini game (python 2.7)

Tags: python

I've been learning python and I was creating a mini-game and did good so far. I need ideas to give each player a turn to attack, First here is the code:

```
from random import randint
class Dragon:
    def __init__(self,name,health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
    def kill(self,target): 
        while target.health >= 0:
            if target.health <= 50:
                hit = randint(1,20)
                target.health -= hit
                print '%s hits %s for %s' %(self.name,target.name,hit)
            elif target.health <= 0:
                print '%s has killed %s' %(self.name,target.name)
            else:
                hit = randint(1,50)
                if hit >= 40:
                    target.health -= hit
                    print "%s critically hits %s for %s" %(self.name,target.name,hit)
                else:
                    target.health -= hit
                    print "%s hits %s for %s" %(self.name,target.name, hit)
    def Dead(self):
        if self.health <= 0:
            print "%s is dead" %self.name
class Hero:
    def __init__(self,name,health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
Diet = Dragon('Diet',200)
Pizza = Hero('Pizza', 100)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Diet.kill(Pizza)
```

I will add more methods to the hero class once I figure out how to give turns to each player and my second problem is that the block that prints out the death of a player is not working, I've tried to nest it under each if function and it worked. But I think I shouldn't repeat the same code over and over and there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: You should break your `kill` method up in to smaller methods. It's much easier to figure out what isn't working the way you expect when you have several small pieces as opposed to one big one.

Answer (score 0):

Take the `kill` method out of a while loop, make it so each time the method is called it is just a single attack, rather than going till the other person is dead.

Then stick the entire game in a while loop, with some sentinel value for the end condition, e.g.:

```
GameIsRunning = True
while GameIsRunning:
    #heros action
    #enemies action
    if EndConditionIsMet():
        GameIsRunning = False
```

At the end of each loop check if the game is over, e.g. if all enemies are dead or the hero is dead, and set `GameIsRunning` to false.

**Edit:**

### Dead option 1

As is, the `Dead` method just prints a message. You can't use this for much other than showing the user that so-and-so is dead. But if you want it like this, call it somewhere in either the attack*ers* `kill` method. Or in the game loop. If you want this to get automatically called when the instance dies, then I would wrap up any damage dealing in a method:

```
def DealDamage(self, damage):
    self.health -= damage
    self.Dead()
```

Then use

```
def Kill(self, target):
    #damage picking logic stays the same
    target.DealDamage(damage)
```

### Dead option 2

If you want said `Dead` method to mean that thing do or don't happen, it ought to have a boolean signature, e.g.:

```
def IsDead(self):
    # Stick in a display message here if you like, or let the game do it
    if self.health <= 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then you can let the game decide what to do about the fact that this person is dead. If you want to start adding multiple enemies then (as most games ultimately will), you might consider sticking them in a collection (a list or a dictionary), looping through this to take each enemies' turn if they're still alive, and removing them if they're dead. Then you're end condition can just be

```
if Hero.IsDead() or len(Enemies) == 0:
    return True
```

This way gives you an easy way to spawn more enemies mid-game as well.

Comment: `while True` and a `break`

Comment: There should be a check after each players action. If the hero kills the dragon the dragon doesn't get a turn.

Comment: You shouldn't exit the game loop based on that though. You may well want to add more enemies in after this version, which forces you to re-write the logic. You can stick in a check before each action or implement the logic within each person so that if they're dead, their action consists of nothing.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that the dead method of the enemy should be returned once the health reaches 0 or below to make sure the loop will be break and to add more functions in the future such as loot or power-ups to make sure I don't need to repeat these codes

Comment: See my edits. I like the second way better personally.